# How do I make a bold text in a message sent via answerQuery? telebot nodejs

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

```
const opt = {
        nextOffset: 64,
        cacheTime: 200,
    };
    const answers = bot.answerList(msg.id, opt);
    answers.addArticle({
        id: '2026',
        title: '2026',
        message_text: 'Year 2026',
    });
bot.answerQuery(answers);
```

When the user clicks one of the options, the message_text is sent on behalf of the user. So how do I make the message bold and how do I attach an inlineButton to it? How?